# How to disable all network connections in Java on Windows Server 2008

Tags: java, windows, network-programming, windows-server-2008

Is there a way to run Java VM (`java.exe`) on Windows Server 2008 and disable all network connections using a command line argument or a system variable?

Comment: The solution should be able to disable network per Java VM process, and should be defined from outside the process (not having the process disable its own network).

Comment: This could have been asked a bit better couldn't it.

Comment: you should have said that in the first place.  You've been a SO user long enough to know the importance of providing relevant details when asking questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by enabling default Java security manager. By default no security is enforced so you are allowed to do anything, but if security manager is enabled it will restrict network access, file access and lots of other things unless you specify otherwise in the security policy file.

To enable the default security manager pass this argument to JVM on start.

```
java -Djava.security.manager=default my.main.Class
```

By doing this any network access attempt from inside JVM will throw `java.net.NetPermission`.

This will also break things like file access, so if you need to allow it you will need to specify those in a special security policy file (`-Djava.security.policy=path/to/policy.file`). There should be plenty of examples of how to set it up, just search for "java permissions" to get you started.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same task to test offline installer for our product. All said above is almost right, but creating .policy file is not easy for the first time. Here is what I did:

1. Crated generic policy file that has no permission to resolve host names (see code snippet below);
2. Added `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=pathto/policy.file` in jvm parameters;

generic .policy file content:

```
grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read,write,execute,delete";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
    permission java.net.NetPermission "*";
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "*";
};
```

If something tries to get content outside during the test, it fails with security exception.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I haven't tried that but theoretically you could set the system properties for SOCKS proxy to a non-existent one and according to the documentation all TCP sockets will be tried through the SOCKS proxy - and fail.

Something like this:

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 SomeClass
```

Comment: I could set a dummy proxy and have it fail, but I would prefer to be able to tell Java "you may not use the network".

Comment: Yes, this works. It's a bit of a dirty hack, but for quick tests it's easier to set up than configuring a security manager, which will by default restrict many other things beside network access.