# Disable "internet access" for JVM?

Tags: java

I'd like to know if there is a way to tell the JVM that it cannot connect to any web resource for a certain Java program, or to immediately fail when doing so, i.e. to do a software equivalent of turning off internet access with a hardware switch. 
This is to assist an automated test, disabling the system's firewall is no option for me.

**Background:** 
I'm currently working on a Java issue where XML identity transformation does not work with a DOCTYPE referenced in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="32px"
     height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
<!-- content.... -->
</svg>
```

The standard behavior of DocumentBuilderFactory, TransformerFactory etc. is to access the web for the missing entities. 
While the fix suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398602/1143126 (a NullEntityResolver) resolved most of my problems, I'd like to test this functionality for regression in an automated way in an "offline environment".

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645588/how-to-disable-all-network-connections-in-java

Comment: I would definitely go with Java Security. If anything can be guaranteed JVM-wide, this is it.

Comment: @Dunes Looks promising, thanks! I should have searched for "Network connection" instead of "Internet connection"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by Dunes helped a lot (issue [How to disable all network connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645588/how-to-disable-all-network-connections-in-java) is related), I overlooked that other question.

Here is what I will use to prevent network connections:

- Start the test case with JVM arguments *-Djava.security.manager=default -Djava.security.policy=/java.policy*
- As java.policy, I use the default file I found with my Java installation, and added the following lines s.t. stuff works with TestNG:

  ```
  // // additional permissions for running TestNG // // 

  // TestNG reads a lot of properties...
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";

  // TestNG connects to a local port for debugging, and does some reflection magic
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:*", "connect,resolve";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";

  // needs at least read access to (default) test suite folder location
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:/Users/<me>/AppData/Local/Temp/-", "read, write";

  // if the test case (or, data provider) accesses any other files, add their location. or do it the lazy way:
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:/-", "read, write";
  ```

With that configuration, any access to an external source such as www.w3.org will result in an AccessControlException:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.w3.org:80 connect,resolve)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [XML catalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog) storing the external schemas (xsd+dtd) on your local disk. That speeds up normal processing too, and allows fast offline development.

It is a standard mechanism.

*(Especially worthwile for XHTML as there is a large amount of HTML entities.)*

Comment: Nice hint, thank you! I guess this is cleaner than my NullEntityResolver. 
But I guess this requires some effort getting to know how to configure things...

Comment: I cannot recall the effort, but yes entirely out-of-the-box the configuration is not. In fact I did first an entity resolver to switch from PUBLIC to SYSTEM (local disk). But that is overhead too.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I haven't tested this, but I would think it should be possible to create [`java.net.SocketImplFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketImplFactory.html) which creates `SocketImpl`s that raise appropriate exceptions when eg. `connect` is called.

As others have pointed out, there is also the possibility to define a security manager. The main difference would be, I guess, what kind of exceptions would be thrown by that. I don't think there's any way to prevent such a solution from throwing `SecurityException`s rather than `SocketException`s or other `IOException`s, which may be important to test the error handling code correctly.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: If you set it using `Socket.setSocketImplFactory`, at least all code that uses `java.net.Socket`s would be forced to use it.

Comment: It can only be called once. You are admittedly right about NIO, however. That may or may not be a problem depending on OP's situation, though. I can't say I know if the XML processing tools use `java.net` or NIO.