# Disable internet access when calling java -jar

Tags: networking, command-line, java

I'm testing six distinct .jar-files that all need to handle the possibility of no online access.

Unfortunately, I am on a network disc, so disabling the network connection or pulling the ethernet cable does not work *unless* I move all the files to `/tmp` or `/scratch` and change my `$HOME` environment variable, all of which I'd rather not have to do as it ends up being a lot of work.

Is there a way to invoke `java -jar` and disable the process from accessing the internet? I have not found any such flag in the `man`-pages. Is there perhaps a UNIX-way of doing this, as in:

```
disallowinternetaccess java -jar Foo.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell your Java program to access the network through a proxy.  For all internet access this would be a SOCKS5 proxy.

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=socks.example.com MyMain
```

I believe that if no proxy is running you should get an appropriate exception in your program.  If you need full control of what is happening, you can look into - and possibly modify - http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html for details.

Note:  You can do this without any native Unix stuff, so this question fits perfectly fine on SO.

Comment: People over at SO requested that I post here instead

Comment: Just one and not a moderator.  (High rep can see deleted posts).  That was because you asked for a Unixy solution which is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You need just turn on SecurityManager: `-Djava.security.manager=default`

see details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645781/814304

With this solution you can even handle which resource you want to show and which to hide.